# In Svelte can't get a component list refreshed based on value on another one

Tags: svelte-3

New with Svelte, I think I haven't yet the correct way of thinking to do this simple thing which is working in vanilla Javascript with help of jQuery for DOM and Ajax.

Simplified case: two columns in a page. First one is filled at page load, each value is a component. When clicking on a component, a web service is called to get data, fill in a variable or a store (tried both). I can get back the value picked up, pass it to the component which has to get related values for the second list, but it works only at component creation.
Ajax call ok on onMount event, but not on reactive event when the id of the selected component changes.
Question is: what is the Svelte way of doing that ?
Demo code in REPL via link hereafter.
Thanks !

https://svelte.dev/repl/92ce738b7af54a1494d88bb6632e3ed3?version=3.29.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution, so answer in case useful for someone else as there is a functional sample code. Otherwise, I delete.

The issue was the reactivity not fired because the variable modified was not not in the reactivity statement but in the function called, filterById.

The following line $: filtered_component2_list = component2_list.filter(filterById); Had been replaced by $: filtered_component2_list =component2_list.filter( item => {if (item.id === id_comp2) return item })

The REPL has been updated and works fine.